# Flutter Hero Animation transitioning Opacity and/or Color

Tags: flutter, animation, opacity, hero

The Hero Widget effectively transitions size and position between two screens. How would you extend it to include opacity so that it effectively fades out the child of one screen whilst fading in the child of the second screen during the animation.

I have tried to achieve this with FadeTransitions connected to the ModalRoute.of(context).animation and secondaryAnimation but it does not achieve this result at all. Instead only one child of each occurrence of the Hero is visible.

**Page 1##**

```
Hero(
 tag: 'test',
 transitionOnUserGestures: true,
 child: FadeTransition(
   opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
     .animate(ModalRoute.of(context)?.animation ?? const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1)),
   child: FadeTransition(
     opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0)
       .animate(ModalRoute.of(context)?.secondaryAnimation ?? const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1)),
      child: Container(color: UIColor.blue, height: 100, width: 110),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

**Page 2##**

```
Hero(
 tag: 'test',
 transitionOnUserGestures: true,
 child: FadeTransition(
   opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 0, end: 1)
     .animate(ModalRoute.of(context)?.animation ?? const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1)),
   child: FadeTransition(
     opacity: Tween<double>(begin: 1, end: 0)
       .animate(ModalRoute.of(context)?.secondaryAnimation ?? const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1)),
      child: Container(color: UIColor.green, height: 60, width: 120),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

I would further like to be able to transition the `Color` instead of opacity in an AnimatedBuilder using the `ModalRoute.of(context).animation` as the animation attribute of the builder, but have encountered the same problem.

This is contained in a standard `CupertinoPageRoute` but the result is identical when using a Material `Route` as well.

Clearly this is not the correct approach. I presume it is because I am falsely making an assumption that both widgets are present during the transition, but my attempt with the `flightRouteBuilder` lead to almost identical results.

How would you go about this.

Update ##
This works perfectly when Transitioning with UserGestures, but does not when transitioning via `Navigator.push()` or `Navigator.pop()`:

```
Hero(
  tag: 'test',
  transitionOnUserGestures: true,
  flightShuttleBuilder: (flightContext, animation, flightDirection, fromHeroContext, toHeroContext) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Positioned.fill(child: FadeTransition(opacity: animation, child: fromHeroContext.widget)),
      Positioned.fill(child: FadeTransition(opacity: ReverseAnimation(animation), child: toHeroContext.widget)),
            ]);
          },
     child: Container(color: UIColor.green, width: 120, height: 60),

),
```

Comment: You're not addressing the problem. Of course I would use a ColorTween, the issue is that only one Widget is displayed in the transition and therefore it would be equally impossible to transition between the two. You don't need a full Widget to run this. Simply but exactly that is any Navigation Router you like. Perhaps you could read questions before commenting.

Comment: Someone deleted their comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be certain that this is a solution however replacing the hero on each page with this has worked and is operating correctly for both push, pop and user gestures. From what I can see, Hero's default flightShuttleBuilder will only render one Widget but hold the Size and Positional parameters of both.

To add additional transition's involving the Widget on each screen, it is necessary to put both Widgets in the flightShuttleBuilder. It is then necessary to access the secondaryAnimation of the route transition via ModalRoute.of(context).secondaryAnimation.

To create the FadeTransition that I wanted, both the from context and to context are placed in a stack. They fill their container as their own Widget will override the size constraint. And then they each invoke a different FadeTransition, one using the flightShuttleBuilder's animation and the second using the `ModalRoute.of(context).secondaryAnimation`.

**#Page 1**

```
 Hero(
   tag: 'test',
   transitionOnUserGestures: true,
   flightShuttleBuilder: (flightContext, animation, flightDirection, fromHeroContext, toHeroContext) {

     return Stack(children: [
       Positioned.fill(child: FadeTransition(
         opacity: animation, child: fromHeroContext.widget),
       ),
       Positioned.fill(
         child: FadeTransition(
           opacity: ReverseAnimation(ModalRoute.of(context)?.secondaryAnimation ?? animation),
             child: toHeroContext.widget)),
      ]);
    },
    child: Container(color: UIColor.blue, width: 100, height: 100),
  );
```

**#Page 2**

Identical accept the child of the Hero Widget is:

```
Container(color: UIColor.green, width: 120, height: 60),
```

Edit
**Therefore**

The objective is to override the FlightShuttleBuilder to include both Widgets. Those Widgets need to be in a stack and each wrapped with position.fill. Then one can animated as one normally would from using `ModalRoute.of(context).animation` and `ModalRoute.of(context).secondaryAnimation`.

For example:

```
Hero(
  tag: 'test',
  transitionOnUserGestures: true,
  flightShuttleBuilder: (flightContext, animation, flightDirection, fromHeroContext, toHeroContext) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Positioned.fill(child: fromHeroContext.widget),
      Positioned.fill(child: toHeroContext.widget),
    ]);
   },
   child: FadeTransition(
     opacity: ModalRoute.of(context)?.animation ?? const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1),
      child: FadeTransition(
        opacity: ReverseAnimation(ModalRoute.of(context)?.secondaryAnimation ?? const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(1)),
        child: Container(color: UIColor.blue, width: 100, height: 100),
      ),
    ),
  );
```